# How can I detect the inner html change in a div with angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<div id="myDiv">Some value comes here dynamically from server</div>',
})
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
@Input()

  ngOnInit() {
      //execute my function when a content change is occured in #myDiv      
  });
 }
}
```

And if a content change has occurred in "#myDiv" I want to execute a function.
How can I achieve this functionality?
I also tried the (change) event in angular.

Comment: what do you mean by **content change**?

Comment: The content of "#myDiv" change during some service call from the server.

Comment: are you using ngmodel there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though it looks to be a simple one, but it can be achieved using child component and Input, Output variables.

Child Component for displaying the content from the service

```
@Component({
  selector: 'title',
  template: `
    <div> {{title}}</div> 
  `,
})
export class TitleComponent implements ngOnChanges{

  @Input() title:string="";
  @Output() titleChanged:EventEmitter<string>=new EventEmitter<string>();
  constructor(){
  //service call goes here
  }
  ngOnChanges(){
  console.log(this.val);
  this.titleChanged.emit(this.title);
  } 

}
```

Parent component will be as

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <title (titleChanged)="changedTitle($event)" [title]="title"></title>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string; 
  title:string="some title";
  val:string;
  constructor() {
    this.val="";

  }

   changedTitle(va){
    console.log(va);

  }
}
```

Explanation:

1. When service call is made and the title value gets changed.
2. On change of the input property the ngOnChanges will be triggered automatically.
3. The **titleChanged** is Output() variable and emits a value when ever ngOnChanges is executed.
4. When the titleChanged is triggered, the associated method in the **changedTitle()** will be executed.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/aSyZsV7M2BRJgWExVSWE?p=preview)**

Note: In order to show this is working I have used an text box and assigning it to the div element.

Comment: got it Aravind. Thanks

Comment: @Aravind, you plunker is broken

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs check it now!