# Angular 2 Update the @input value if the object property changed

Tags: angular, observable

I have a ListComponent and a ListItemComponent which the input value is from the ListComponent, and if the ListComponent Observable  value of list changes the ListItemComponent value also should change.how to implement it?Thanks

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Have a look at my [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596458/how-can-i-detect-the-inner-html-change-in-a-div-with-angular-2/42596914#42596914) which helps you to understand the onChanges

Answer (score 0):

So traditionally using ngOnChanges would fire when your `@Input` gets updated.  However, in order to reduce the computational burden, Angular will only check the object reference to see if a change occurred in an object.

Changing the object reference should do the trick -- so make sure that instead of mutating the object you are reassigning it or cloning it back to itself.

Example:

```
//don't do this

myArray[0] = "1"

//do this

myArray = [1].concat(myArray.slice(1));
```

Of course, the child should have the original reference, which will be reflected as it's the same object reference.  So you should only use something similar to the above if you really need to fire ngOnChanges.