# ionic 2 - Dynamic ion-title

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2

What is the best approach to dynamically setting the title in my ion-navbar if I have the navbar set in the root HTML ? e.g.

app.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{some title here}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>

<ion-footer>
</ion-footer>
```

Currently, I am giving each component view it's own ion-navbar in its corresponding HTML file, but the title is flickering between views and I think this is because a new navbar is being created each time.

Any advice would be great.

Thaanks!

Comment: This is a similar requirement but not exactly same as that. [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596458/how-can-i-detect-the-inner-html-change-in-a-div-with-angular-2/42596914#42596914)

Comment: Not really ionic2 related but the way I like to do this is to define a projection over all of the application routes that map's each one to menu headings and titles. You can then access it it in a higher level component. I'm not sure if that would work for ionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently, I am giving each component view it's own ion-navbar in its
>   corresponding HTML file

That's exactly how you should handle the `ion-navbar`. If you were thinking in defining a custom component to contain the navbar and reuse it in the entire app, don't do it (@mhartington from Ionic team explains why you shouldn't do that in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936198/ionic-2-global-navbar-for-the-app/37808988#37808988)).

In order to solve the flickering issue, please try by removing the `ion-header` from the `app.html` file and just leave the

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Then in every page, include the header with the proper title:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{ pageTitle }}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Great answer, and great to know not to spend a bunch of time creating a global ion-nav bar, however the issue was not setting the menu to be persistent!

Comment: Accepting the answer as my question was actually how to set a dynamic ion title rather than how to remove the flickering issue!