# bind var to html so ui changes after async subscribe call

Tags: html, angular, dom, asynchronous, typescript

I am working on a page that charts figures but cant get my ui to update from my json so i have simplified the problem -> change my var 'title' in UI after async call.

How do i update binded HTML element/ ts var {{title}} element after a subscribe service returns from async call?

My code is as follows

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpWebServiceService1 } from './http-web-service-service';
import { Chart } from './bar-chart-demo/chartModel';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpWebServiceService1]
})
export class AppComponent {
    title:string;

  constructor(HttpWebServiceService1: HttpWebServiceService1){
    this.title = 'see this';
    HttpWebServiceService1.getHTTP()
      .subscribe(
        charts => 
        { 
          this.title="now this";      
        },
      );

}
}
```

My html is

```
<div class="flex-container-header" 
    fxLayout="row" 
    fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
  <div class="flex-item" fxFlex=10>
    <img src="../../assets/img/ami_logo1.png" ng-href="www.mysite.ie" >
  </div>
</div> 
'<h1> {{title}} </h1>'
</div>
```

Comment: If it's not changing automatically, have you tried triggering the change detection manually?

Comment: no, how do i doi that?

Comment: possible solution you can have a look is [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596458/how-can-i-detect-the-inner-html-change-in-a-div-with-angular-2/42596914#42596914)

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger change detection manually you can use the `ChangeDetectorRef` provider.

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){} //<-- inject in constructor
//later use like this:
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

Documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html