# How to Get input in one page and print in next Html page using Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Am new to Angular 2, and am working with data binding I don't know how to print the value from one page to another throw components.I am trying with this piece of code but it prints the value in the same page, If anybody knows the logic help me, Thanks in advance!

**//child.component.ts**

```ts
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Student} from './student';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'child-one',
    template: `
       <nav>
       <h3>{{childTitle}}</h3>

       <div>
          First Name:<input (input)="student.fname=$event.target.value" /> <br/>
          Last Name:<input (input)="student.lname=$event.target.value" />
          <button (click)="addStudent()">Add Student</button>
      </div >
    `,   
})

export class ChildOneComponent {

    constructor(private _router: Router){ }

    @Output('addStudentEvent') 
    addStdEvent = new EventEmitter<Student>();

    student = new Student();
    childTitle = '---Child One---';

    addStudent() {
       this.addStdEvent.emit(this.student);
       this._router.navigate(['name']);
    }       
}
```

**//Parent.component.ts**

```ts
import {Component,EventEmitter,Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Student} from './student';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
   selector: 'input-output',
   template: `
      <h1>{{parentTitle}}</h1>
      <p>Name: {{stdFullName}}</p>

      <child-one  (addStudenztEvent) = "saveData($event)"></child-one>                      
    `
    // providers: [Student]
    })

export class ParentComponent {
    parentTitle = 'Parent Component';
    stdAddMsg = 'Add Student';  

    //Property used in parent
    stdFullName = '';

    saveData(std) {
        this.stdFullName = std.fname + ' ' + std.lname ;
    }       
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596458/how-can-i-detect-the-inner-html-change-in-a-div-with-angular-2/42596914#42596914)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is about "Communication between components"

You can find answer here:

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service