# Output() not emitting event

Tags: angular, output, eventemitter

I have the following architecture:

```
UiControlsModule
|- Component 1
|- Component 2
```

Module 1 is imported and exported in **SharedModule**.

```
CasesModule
|- CaseListComponent
|- // several other components
```

SharedModule is imported into CasesModule.

Now, inside CaseListComponent I have an instance of Component 1 (of UiControlsModule):

```
<cre-question-group
    (valueChanged)="catchValueChange(question)">
</cre-question-group>
```

I'm trying to catch the value change here, which I have defined in Component 1:

```
@Output() valueChanged = new EventEmitter<Question>();

someMethod(question: Question) {
    this.valueChanged.emit(question);
}
```

The method `someMethod()` is called, and it emits the event. However, I cannot catch the event in my CaseListComponent. When I inspect `valueChanged`, I can also see that there's no subscriber on it (the Array is empty).

I assume, it's because it's going from one module to the other one, but not sure how to solve it.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

**@Update:** 
Is it possible that it doesn't work because it's a component of another module? Normally that should work, or am I wrong?

**@Update 2:**

Now I tried to implement it with a messages service communicating over a subject and observable, but for some miracle reason this doesn't work as well.
Here's how I implemented it:

**question-group.component.ts:**

```
catchValueChange(question: Question) {    

    this.messagesService.sendComponentChangeEvent(question);
}
```

**messages.service.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MessagesService {

    constructor() { }

    // Observable string sources
    private componentChangeEvent = new Subject<Question>();

    // Observable string streams
    componentValueChanged$ = this.componentChangeEvent.asObservable();

    // Service message commands
    sendComponentChangeEvent(question: Question) {
        this.componentChangeEvent.next(question); // <-- breakpoint reaches this point as expected. After, nothing happens - and there's no observer on componentChangeEvent.
    }
}
```

**case-list.component.html:**

```
  ngOnInit() {

    // watch for changes on edit of the components
    this.subscription = this.messagesService.componentValueChanged$.subscribe( (question: any) => {
      console.log(question.id + " (" + question.type + "): " + question.selection);
    });
```

In the template I subscribe on the Observable, but it never reaches that point. I assume that the error is somewhere in messages.service.ts?
Dev console shows no errors.

Comment: use `this.valueChanged.next(question);` instead of `this.valueChanged.emit(question);`

Comment: This doesn't work neither.

Comment: When do you call someMethod? Make sure it's called after the component is initialised

Comment: Also, do you have any module loaded dynamically?

Comment: someMethod is called when a value of an input changes, so it is called after initialization. Nope, unfortunately no modules loaded dynamically. Every module is imported in the imports array of another module.

Comment: A workaround is to use a shared service with Subjects to propagate the change. But that won't explain the problem if everything is loaded statically...

Comment: can you reproduce using a plunker? Use [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596458/how-can-i-detect-the-inner-html-change-in-a-div-with-angular-2/42596914#42596914) demo plunker to start with the initial files

Comment: I'm about to implement a shared service which communicates over an Observable. No idea why it doesn't work, but I'll keep it that way for now. Thanks all for your help :)

Comment: Ok, it's really strange but the services method doesn't work as well, so I think there's some architectural problem... I've updated my question and added the solution with messages. Can anyone please help? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter in your template event handler function **must** be called `$event`. You can call it whatever you like in your handler method declaration (in the component class definition).

Try like this :

**template.html**

```
<cre-question-group (valueChanged)="catchValueChange($event)"></cre-question-group>
```

(instead of)

```
<cre-question-group
    (valueChanged)="catchValueChange(question)">
</cre-question-group>
```

**typescript**

```
catchValueChange(question: Question) {
    console.log('question', question);
}
```

Comment: May i know which one is parent Component and child component can you share in this question

Comment: emit function will work only child to parent way NOT parent to child way

Comment: So cre-question-group (QuestionGroupComponent) is called from CaseListComponent. So there's no real parent-child relation since they're in seperate modules.